# How to remove all + signs from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string that looks like `KATIE+DAMAN-SUZANNE+DANIELS`

How do I replace *both* + signs? I tried the following which does not work.

```
string.replace(/+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: `VM639:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat` You need to escape it `var updated = string.replace(/\+/g, ' ');`

Comment: How do I escape it?

Comment: like my comment or the duplicate states

Comment: `var str = str = 'KATIE+DAMAN-SUZANNE+DANIELS'

console.log(str.replace(/\+/g, ' ')
`

Comment: wonderful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g,'')
```

You have tried this it's working